# Unit Test - AngularJS1 and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to test a method of a controller in project using jasmine. This function basically for calling http get request.

inside controller method like belows:

```
   $scope.performValidation = function (tries) {
              var requestParams = {
                    lyToken: true,
                    emToken: $scope.lyToken,
                    companyID: $rootScope.companyID
                };

                $http({
                    url: eAPI + '${apiContext}/emToken',
                    method: 'GET',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    params: requestParams,
                    headers: {'authorization': "Bearer " + $cookies.get('access_token')}
                }).then(function (data) {
                    redeemPoints();
                }, function (status) {
                });
            };
```

eAPI and apiContext are variables and those are defined in jsp file. When I tried to implement unit test return an error called   "ReferenceError: eAPI is not defined". I'm new to jasmine framework and please give me a solution.

My unit test code as follows:

```
 it('testing', function () {
        $scope.performValidation(0);
    });
```

And eAPI variable is defined in jsp file as follows:

```
 var eAPI = '<%=prop.getProperty("eAPIHTTPSDomain")%>' + ':' + '<%=prop.getProperty("eAPIManagerAPIPortHTTPS")%>';
```

Comment: The message says: `emojotAPI is not defined`. It probably also refers to the line where th problem is. So analyze the situation by **reading** the error message. You haven't posted the relevant code, so we can't help.

Comment: Angular unit tests don't know and care about what the JSP files do. If your code relies on a global variable to be defined, then define it in your tests.